# List sent through actionlink is always null in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

In my MVC app I have a view that generates checkboxes for every items in the list based on a boolean properties.

The view displays fine without problem.

I want to get every items in the list based on if the checkbox is checked or not.

The first step is this actionlink:

```
<p>
    Send Items: @Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "SendItems")
</p>
```

and here's the method as written in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult SendItems(IList<ObjInfo> listToSend)
    {
        m_ListInventoryToSend = new List<ObjInfo>();

        foreach (var item in listToSend.Where(item => item.m_IsSelected))
        {
            m_ListInventoryToSend.Add(item);
        }

        return View(m_ListInventoryToSend);
    }
```

Now I am facing many issues and since I'm learning how to code an MVC app I really need your help:

- When the debug hits the method, the listToSend object is always null;
- Also, each hiddenfield for those checkboxes are false even if the value "checked" is true;
- If I put the "HttpPost" attribute over the method, the app returns a NotFound error.

Thank you!

Comment: Herve, Lists should be sent by post-ing

Comment: the reason it throws the error when you do the httpPost is because you have to tell the action link to send as a post. pass `FormMethod.Post` in the actionlink method.

Comment: How are you creating the checkboxes?  Sounds like the binder is not able to bind the checkboxes to the input parameter.

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].m_IsSelected) in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sent lists through an `ActionLink`, (well unless you do some **really ugly** query string building).

What you should do, first of all, is create a model that will hold the booleans:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<ObjInfo> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Set your model in your view:

```
@model MyModel
```

Loop through your Model items to put a checkbox (has to be a `for` loop for model binding to work):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendItems", "ControllerName")
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        @* Have hidden fors to keep any other data in the class*@
        @HiddenFor(m => m.Items[i].Id)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Items[i].IsChecked)
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Then, have a Post method, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendItems(MyModel model)
{
    foreach (var item in model.Items.Where(item => item.IsSelected))
    {
        m_ListInventoryToSend.Add(item);
    }

    //rest of your post action
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Now I have my List, and I can continue my work.

Comment: @HerveS No problems! Glad I could help :)